# Which is better to listen events from smart contract, Contract.on or response.wait()?

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js

Hi I am now trying to create a simple dApp to learn Solidity and interaction with it.

I am wondering which is a better way for listening events from smart contracts and applying state changes from transactions to the front end, using `on` method from Contract instance or `wait` from TransactionResponse.

I am using ethers.js, and it gives you something like this to listen events from smart contracts:

```
const myContract = new Contract(address, abi, provider);
myContract.on("eventName", (...args) => { // do something here}
```

Also calling the transaction method from the contract instance like the above, it returns `Promise<ethers.ContractTransaction>` type.
The returned object has `wait` method and it waits until the transaction has been mined  like below:

```
myContract.someFunction(...args).then(async (response: ContractTransaction) => {
  await response.wait();
  // do something after transaction has been mined
}
```

**ContractTransaction is extended from TransactionResponse

Considering two ways to handle values after transactions have been mined, is one better the other?
Or is there even another way better than these?

I would imagine "better" depends on how I structure components (I am using React) and other things.
But I would like to know your preference at least :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first one would be better because it will passively listen for changes and update when they happen. With the 2nd one, you have to stop the execution of the function and whatever else you're doing in order to display something after the transaction happens. This means you'd have to set up some sort of loading page, but if the user leaves before the transaction is mined then what you will be waiting for is lost.